# Show res.partner on PoS interface- Odoo

Tags: widget, odoo

Can anyone please provide some help on how to show a partner details on the PoS web interface. There is no clear explanation of how to inherit and edit the pos.xml and pos widgets to be able to show the customer on PoS interface payment screen widget.

Atleast if anyone can help me understand how I can get the res.partner called on js and use the result to show on the web interface via xml, it would be really helpful. A very brief snippet of code would be enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

John

Try to look into "screen.js" file under point of sale -> static -> src -> js

It allows to set current screen by screen selector.